# Nodemailer get User Email from the contact us form as a dynamic value.

Tags: angularjs, nodemailer

In my app I am using angular 1 and we are using node mailer 0.7.1. currently we are sending the email from a specific email address being set. The requirement is to have the email received from the email address which User is entering when the user is filling the form.

So, that we don't have any hard coded email address set and whenever the customer service is receiving the email they should be able to click reply and respond to the customer.

Here is how the code looks like currently.

```
var mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.name + ' <info@xyz.com>', // sender address
        to: 'csr@abc.com', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Contact Us', // Subject line
        html: content // html body
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind I figured it out. here is the trick.

```
from: '"' + req.body.name + '" <' + req.body.email + '>',
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let senderEmail = 'info@xyz.com'; here you can give dynamic value 
let receivers = csr@abc.com'; if multiple receivers than you can loop there.
var mailOptions = {
    from: req.body.name + senderEmail, // sender address
    to: receivers, // list of receivers
    subject: 'Contact Us', // Subject line
    html: content // html body
};
```